# SQl Server SSIS Create A Dataset From An Array?

Tags: arrays, sql-server, ssis

I have a text file that holds a list of filenames held in a windows share.
My SSIS package runs a single .BAT file in an SSIS ‘Execute Task’ that will update all or some of the files in the share.  I want to be able to identify if any of the files have not been updated by the BAT file.

To do that I need to compare the modified time from the files before the BAT file was executed and the modified times from after the BAT file is run.  I therefore need a list/array/dataset in my SSIS package of the files and their modified times before the BAT files is executed.  The list can then be used in a For Each loop to check the modified time has changed after the BAT file has run.

The problem is how to represent this list in my SSIS package.
If I do it as a ‘Script Task’ generated array I will have to use two arrays.
One array would be the filename and one would be the modified time.
I think I can reference them both in a loop but it feels a bit poor to do it that way.

What I really need is the list to be a dataset with two columns or an array with two columns.
Is there a way of doing this or am I missing something silly?  I know an ‘Execute SQL Task’ can create a dataset but how can I create a dataset in an ‘Execute SQL Task’ from an array?

Comment: Could you not update the bat file to output the files it updated?

Comment: You can save the list in script task to a object variable and iterate that. Or you can do the whole thing in a script task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store datasets in an Object Variable in the package, and they will persist throughout the run of the package.

You can create the object variable in a script task the same way you would create a DataTable in any .net code.

Comment: I don't see any option in the 'Script Task' to output a result set in the way you can from an 'Execute SQL Task'.

Comment: Is the way to do it to set the  'Script Task' to receive an object variable in the ReadWriteVariables properties and then in the script create the Dataset so that I can issue a command in the script (VB) to set the variable:-    Dts.Variables("User::MyDataSetObject").Value = MyScriptedDataSet?

Comment: set the variable to the list.  1. Add the object variable to read/write list. 2. load the data to the list in your case probably using a FileInfo method. 3. Set the variable = theList

Comment: Yes both of the last two comments describe the process exactly right.

Comment: OK I understand.   I did a variation on this in the end but it is working.      First I created a Data Flow task.  It has a Script Component as a Source and outputs to a 'RecordSet Destination'  which I set to an Object Variable.  The Object variable is then set on the ForEach Loop Container that uses the variable as an 'EDO Enumerator'.  I map the two fields in the ForEach loop to variable names for each pass of the loop and can then pass them to another script task to compare each file's characteristics to see if they have changed.  Thanks all for your help. It sent me in the right direction